# can't save clustering result to an arff file

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, weka, arff

I'm using a java code to save clustering result to an arff file.. 
I've followed the instructions in this site:
http://weka.wikispaces.com/Visualizing+cluster+assignments
but I get an error in the line:

```
    PlotData2D predData = ClustererPanel.setUpVisualizableInstances(train, eval);
```

saying that:

```
    The method setUpVisualizableInstances(Instances, ClusterEvaluation) is undefined for the type ClustererPanel
```

I've tried to google it but I couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the current code:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-dev/3.7.12/weka/gui/explorer/ClustererPanel.java#ClustererPanel

I assume you have to call `setInstances` instead of `setUpVisualizableInstances` now.

But: Why do you use a *visualization* tutorial?

Visualization won't produce an .arff file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, according to this link http://list.waikato.ac.nz/pipermail/wekalist/2014-January/059753.html
this is the way to do it.
I've tried what you've suggested but now I get:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to PlotData2D

Comment: Even if that once worked, it doesn't look as if it ever was meant to be abused this way. Why don't you try to figure out the proper way of doing it, instead of abusing visualization code to dump the clusters?